# Use/Benefit of output parameter in stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, output-parameter

Where do we need to use output parameter in a stored procedure?

Does anyone have any real time experience to share?

I searched a lot but not able to understand proper use of output parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several good answers already, but one not mentioned is when you need the procedure to return more than one variable.

Example:  Searching for the highest salary a procedure might also return the I.D. of the person and whether they are still employed.

Comment: Actually, I did mentioned that: *"when perfoming select statements and you need some extra data"*...

Comment: @ZoharPeled:  Ah, it wasn't clear to me that the "extra data" came from a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

There are many occasions where you want to get some data back from a stored procedure in the form of an output parameter:

- when inserting data to a table and you need to get the identity value back
- when performing select statements and you need some extra data
- when updating or inserting data and you need some way to know if the operation was successful
- for most if not all of the reasons you need out or ref parameters in c#

There are probably more situations where an output is useful, but I think that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is to pass a value out of the stored procedure.  Either a rowset reference, or a scalar value.  Think of it as turning stored procedures into function calls.